# WPF How to get a UserControl to inherit a Button?

Tags: wpf, button, user-controls

I created a UserControl which consists of a couple ellipses and labels.  I added it just fine to another form and things were looking pretty snazzy.

Then I went to start adding some event handlers and discovered that the control I made did not expose a Click event.  Oops.  Easy to fix, right?  Just go back to the code-behind on the UserControl I made and let it inherit Button.

Unfortunately, doing this caused a "Partial declarations of MyControl must not specify different base classes" message.  This came as a surprise since I haven't declared any other base classes.  Searching for the Partial in question returned no results either.

Is there a way to defeat this issue?  If not, what would be the easiest workaround here?  My goal is simply to get a Click event on the UserControl.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you've declared other base classes :) Just trust compiler :)

When you writing `<UserControl ...></UserControl>` in XAML, you are subclassing UserControl. If you want to subclass a Button, use `<Button ...></Button>` instead and ": Button" in code-behind file.

But I'm strongly encourage you to not subclass Button, its an overkill for you task. You can use MouseLeftButtonUp event instead of the Click event.

Comment: The MouseLeftButtonUp event relies on the button always being clicked by an mouse. When an user presses a Spacebar key, the Click event is fired but the MouseLeftButtonUp is not (the spacebar is not a left mouse button).