# WPF KeyBinding Command not triggering in Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, custom-controls

I am building a WPF Custom Control (Note: **NOT** a user control). The c# code for the control is defined as follows:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using MvvmFoundation.Wpf;

namespace TextBoxWithInputBinding
{
    public class AutoComp : Control
    {
        static AutoComp()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AutoComp), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AutoComp)));
        }

        public AutoComp()
        {
            DownCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Down");
            });
            PressedCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Pressed");
            });
        }

        public RelayCommand DownCommand
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(DownCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DownCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DownCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DownCommand", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(AutoComp), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public RelayCommand PressedCommand
        {
            get { return (RelayCommand)GetValue(PressedCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PressedCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PressedCommand", typeof(RelayCommand), typeof(AutoComp), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

I define the template for the control in Generic.xaml as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TextBoxWithInputBinding">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoComp}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AutoComp}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            >
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox>
                                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                                    <KeyBinding Key="Down" Command="{TemplateBinding DownCommand}"/>
                                </TextBox.InputBindings>
                            </TextBox>
                            <Button Content="Press me" Command="{TemplateBinding PressedCommand}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

When I press the "Press me" button the PressedCommand is triggered (the word "Pressed" appears in the output window - however, when I type in the TextBox and press the down key, nothing happens.

What do I need to do to make the DownCommand fire?

Comment: You should check this entry;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686248/wpf-command-binding-for-custom-usercontrol

Comment: @orhun.begendi Thanks, but if you look at my code, that is what I am already doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer: I need regular Binding not TemplateBinding: I replaced

```
<KeyBinding Key="Down" Command="{TemplateBinding DownCommand}"/>
```

with

```
<KeyBinding Key="Down"
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DownCommand}"/>
```

I would still like to know why the Button binding works with TemplateBinding but the TextBox KeyBinding does not!!!

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered you should replace the `TemplateBinding` with the usual binding markup and use a `{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}`

```
<KeyBinding Key="Down"
    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=DownCommand}"/>
```

> I would still like to know why the Button binding works with TemplateBinding but the TextBox KeyBinding does not?

Because `TemplateBinding` is optimized and has some limitations compared to using an ordinary `Binding`. For example it only works directly inside the `ControlTemplates`'s visual tree but not in `DataTrigger`s and `KeyBinding`s.

You will find more information about this here:

[WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)